# file_get_contents Default headers

Tags: php, http-headers, recaptcha

I was wondering what is the default `Content-Type` header option when requesting a json string from an API.

I've noticed even if the requested `Content-Type` is `application/json` the response header `Content-Type` will be `text/html`

Does file_get_contents set the headers automatically based on what it is requesting or does it have a default one that is used always?

Comment: The *response* headers are set by the contacted webserver/script/API, not by `file_get_contents`.

Comment: @mario so even if I added the context to the file_get_contents it would not make a different?

Comment: Because it seem like you can request what content-type you want the api to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `file_get_contents` set the headers automatically based on what it is requesting or does it have a default one that is used always?

I think no defaults. For the `context` parameter you read below and see the 4-th example in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

> A valid context resource created with [`stream_context_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php). If you don't need to use a custom context, you can skip this parameter by NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Tested with Wireshark.

PHP 5.5.8 sends:

> POST /path HTTP/1.0
>
> Host: example.com
>
> Content-Length: [appropriate number]
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

For the following context:

```
$options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => $content
            )
        );
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
```